# date and time is wrong 12-31-1969, 7:00 PM

Tags: php, mysql, date

This is converting the stored `datetime` in my `mysql` but every time it keeps giving `12-31-1969, 7:00 PM` I keep finding several responses explaining why it is happening but not a way to fix it

How would i edit this with out messing it up because i want to keep it the same layout but fix it to display the correct time and date

How this code is running is this first echo calls on time_ago which runs the 2 lines above it then it travels down the timeAgo function to reach the last echo which calls on the function at the top

```
function converttotime_date($date) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    return date("m-d-Y, g:i A", $date);
}

$curenttime= $row['post_date'];
$time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
echo "".timeAgo($time_ago)."


function timeAgo($time_ago){
$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
// Seconds
if($seconds < 60){
    echo "$seconds seconds ago";
}
//Minutes
else if($minutes < 60){
    if($minutes==1){
        echo "1 minute ago";
    }
    else{
        echo "$minutes minutes ago";
    }
}
//Hours
else if($hours <= 12){
    if($hours==1){
        echo "1 hour ago";
    }else{
        echo "$hours hours ago";
    }
}
//Hours
else if($hours <= 24){
        echo "Today, ".converttotime($time_ago)." ";
}

//Hours
else if($hours <= 48){
        echo "Yesterday, ".converttotime($time_ago)." ";
}
//Days
else if($days > 2){
        echo " ".converttotime_date($time_ago)." ";
}

}
```

Comment: GIGO... If you input "I am a happy person", you'll get a bad date and that defaults to the date/time you're seeing, so check for the results of `strtotime` and handle accordingly.  LAW: NEVER TRUST INPUT FROM END USERS. Edit: The function description is at http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: are you saying that mysql is storing it incorrectly?  if yes, what is the data-type you are using in mysql? `datetime` wont accept this,  this has to be `varchar` or change your string to acceptable format.

Comment: the date in the database is correct its just giving wrong date and time espacialy the year

Comment: im using datetime in mysql and the stored data is this 2014-06-04 02:04:27

Comment: ill post the other function in a sec

Comment: dates normally need to be wrapped in inverted commas. I suspect that you're missing those.

Comment: can you show what u mean because i have tried several way but even that hasn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line `timeAgo` function

```
//Days
else if($days > 2){
        echo " ".converttotime_date($time_ago)." ";  # this wrong
}
```

as `$time_ago` is already a Unix Time stamp so doesn't need to be converted.
So instead change it to

```
//Days
else if($days > 2){
        echo date("m-d-Y, g:i A", $time_ago); 
}
```

and `converttotime_date()` is not longer needed. Perhaps change it to a `formatDateDisplay` function?